# indentation of text

Tags: spacing

I have a following simple code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \textbf{Date1} \hfill \textbf{Date2}  \hfill \textbf{Random number} \\
    \indent
    2022 \hfill     2023 \hfill 11111111111111111111 \\
    \indent
\end{document}
```

The result looks like:

[image]

How can I indent `2023` and `11111111111111111111` properly, please?

Desired output is an indentation without the space here:

[image]

Comment: you might want to use a tabbular or array for this.

Comment: All `\hfill`s in one line expand equally until the line is full.  `\hfill`s in different lines have no relation to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities: in the former the horizontal space is equal between the two columns; in the latter there are three columns of equal size.

The `\foo` command is only defined in the group, just to avoid to repeat code that won't be needed later.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll@{}}
\textbf{Date1} & \textbf{Date2} & \textbf{Random number} \\
2022           & 2023           & 11111111111111111111 \\
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip

\begingroup\par
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\columnwidth/3][#1]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
  }%
}%
\noindent
\foo{l}{\textbf{Date1}\\2022}%
\foo{c}{\textbf{Date2}\\2023}%
\foo{r}{\textbf{Random number}\\11111111111111111111}\par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> `\hfill` Produce a rubber length which has no natural space but that
> can stretch horizontally as far as needed

I think you want a table. You can use `tabular`, `tabularx`, `tabularray`

Code with tabularray. I took X columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{showframe}%<-- you can comment in the final document

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {*{3}{X[l]}},
  row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
}
Date1 & Date2 & Random number \\
2022 & 2023 & 11111111111111111111
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]